# Beautiful Soup pip install error

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have tried:

- `pip install beautifulsoup4`
- `pip install beautifulsoup`
- `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`
- `pip3 install beautifulsoup`
- `easy_install beautifulsoup4`
- `easy_install beautifulsoup`

It is for this program:

```
import requests
import beautifulsoup
website = input("What website do you want to look at, please include the full web adress")
session = requests.session()
req = session.get(website)
doc = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(req.content)
print(doc.findAll('a', { "class" : "gp-share" }))
```

In the terminal (I'm on raspberry pi 3) it says I have successfully installed it but then when I run the program it says there is no such thing as `beautiful soup`.

**Any help will be much appreciated**

Comment: Reading the docs will help a lot more than typing in what you think might work. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Intead of `import beautifulsoup` use `import bs4 as bs` and change in your code beautifulsoup references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A package call is case sensitive, if it had been installed successfully, put your Soup constructing code string as follows:

`doc = beautifulsoup.BeautifulSoup(req.content)`

Comment: Could you please quote the exact message.

Comment: `import beautifulsoup
ImportError: No module named 'beautifulsoup'`

Comment: try `import bs4`, and then `doc = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.content)`

Answer (score 0):

The Beautiful Soup [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) includes an example in the tutorial to import the module using `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

So, in your case replace:

`import beautifulsoup` with `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

and

`doc = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(req.content)` with  `doc = BeautifulSoup(req.content)`